# Robot_localization: odometry/gps no output info

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working with robot localization in ubuntu 16.04. I am using bags files with IMU and two GPS. However the IMU data don't give me info about the orientation, so I use mine /get_orientation node to obtain the orientation with the two GPS, getting the robot orientation.

The ekf outputs are working, i am not sure if fine but at least is giving some output. However the problem is the navsat_transform_node wich its output is all zero. So I am not sure where is the problem in that node.

I add the files:

**fix_back(gps):**

```
 header:    
   seq: 2733   
   stamp: 
        secs: 1455210306
        nsecs: 652417898   
   frame_id: "gps" 
status:    
   status: 1   
   service: 1 
latitude: 42.1819562283 
longitude: -8.73968366 
altitude: 384.671 
position_covariance: [1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16000000000000.0]
position_covariance_type: 0
```

**/imu/data:**

```
header: 
  seq: 145690
  stamp: 
    secs: 1455210324
    nsecs: 134030103
  frame_id: "base_imu"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 0.0
orientation_covariance: [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.0156264220278
  y: 0.0181547511189
  z: 0.0154273617187
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0004]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0415387526155
  y: -0.0178170949221
  z: 0.0885146409273
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0004]
```

**/get/orientation(topic with orientation wich is subscribed navsat node):**

```
header: 
  seq: 1644
  stamp: 
    secs: 1455210302
    nsecs: 894764900
  frame_id: "base_imu"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.778295047494
  w: 0.627898733114
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**/odometry/gps:**
I think that maybe the problem is in de frame id

```
header: 
  seq: 2691
  stamp: 
    secs: 1455210292
    nsecs: 652157068
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16000000000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**/odometry/filtered:**

```
header: 
  seq: 51683
  stamp: 
    secs: 1577439407
    nsecs: 801655531
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 156563.13445
      y: -43035.340716
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.687894745035
      w: 0.725810457181
  covariance: [4.999999991019117e-10, 1.8213410266344878e-19, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.7155029258938172e-18, 1.8213410266344009e-19, 4.999999999627129e-10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -4.734606596713057e-19, 0.0, 0.0, 4.99999999319995e-07, -1.4343813184271704e-13, -5.537703876135997e-14, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.4343813184271712e-13, 4.999532936965985e-07, -1.1681062864961878e-11, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5.537703876135998e-14, -1.168106286496188e-11, 4.999790403984765e-07, 0.0, 2.7155029258938396e-18, -4.734606596713306e-19, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.999999685207372e-10]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 376.337918185
      y: -1026.94096739
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.160520859566
  covariance: [3.6023855883949554, 1.204648214979867, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0017902513769453227, 1.2046482149798612, 0.7431464414456158, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000144190040518795, 0.0, 0.0, 4.999876641741591e-07, -2.8393491075641632e-15, -1.1267194434469995e-15, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.839349107564164e-15, 4.999493611311244e-07, -1.188802486830638e-13, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.126719443447e-15, -1.1888024868306388e-13, 4.9994961353661e-07, 0.0, 0.001790251376945311, 0.00014419004051858424, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03574059011903692]
```

Now configuration files:

**ekf_template.yaml:**

```
frequency: 30

sensor_timeout: 0.1

two_d_mode: true #false   zona plana

transform_time_offset: 0.0

transform_timeout: 0.0

print_diagnostics: true

debug: false

debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt

publish_tf: true

publish_acceleration: false 

map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom           # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom          # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

odom0: /get_orientation/odometry    #position + orientation
odom0_config: [true,  true,  true,
               true,  true,  true,
               false,  false,  false,
               false,  false,  false,
               false,  false,  false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: true 
odom0_nodelay: false
odom0_queue_size: 5


odom1: /odometry/gps                #gps in UTM
odom1_config: [true,  true,  true,
               false,  false,  true,
               false,  false,  false,
               false,  false,  false,
               false,  false,  false]
odom1_nodelay: false
odom1_differential: false
odom1_relative: true
odom1_queue_size: 5


pose0: /get_orientation/pose_covariance       #position + orientation
pose0_config: [true,  true,  true,
               true,  true,  true,    
              false,  false,  false,
              false,  false,  false,
              false,  false,  false]
pose0_nodelay: false
pose0_differential: false
pose0_relative: true
pose0_queue_size: 5


imu0: /imu/data                      #imu data
imu0_config: [false,  false,  false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false,  false,  false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5

imu1: /get_orientation/imu_orientation  #orientation + imu data
imu1_config: [false,  false,  false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false,  false,  false,
              false,  false,  false,
              false,  false,  false]
imu1_nodelay: false
imu1_differential: false
imu1_relative: true
imu1_queue_size: 5

imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false

use_control: false
stamped_control: true #false
control_timeout: 0.5
control_config: [false, false, false, false, false, false]
acceleration_limits: [100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
deceleration_limits: [100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
acceleration_gains: [0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]

deceleration_gains: [0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]

process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

**navsat_transform_template.yaml:**

```
frequency: 30

delay: 3.0

magnetic_declination_radians: 0

yaw_offset: 0.0

zero_altitude: false

broadcast_utm_transform: false

broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: false

publish_filtered_gps: true #false

use_odometry_yaw: false

wait_for_datum: false

datum: [55.944904, -3.186693, 0.0, map, base_link]
```

The launch of both nodes:

**ekf_tamplate.launch:**

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_template.yaml" />

  </node>

  <!-- TF'S -->
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="back_broadcaster"
    args="-40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 base_link gps_back" respawn="true" />

  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_broadcaster"
    args="30.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 base_link base_imu" respawn="true" />

  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="front_broadcaster"
    args="40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 base_link gps_front" respawn="true" />

</launch>
```

**navsat_transform_template.launch**

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" clear_params="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/navsat_transform_template.yaml" />      

  </node>
</launch>
```

Here I uploaded the picture of rqt_graph wich maybe give some info to help.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yyi8ahkrumyd5x/rosgraph.png?dl=0

I think that this is the most important info to show you, if somebody need some additional info, ask me for them.
Thank you to everybody.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340729/robot_localization:-odometry/gps-no-output-info/) by [sergiootero](https://answers.ros.org/users/50338/sergiootero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-12-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-01-06**:
Where are you telling `navsat_transform_node` to listen to your new `orientation` topic? I don't see a remap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Tom, I think i found the problem and it was that I had to change a frame_id I wasn´t see.
Thank you for your response, I'll continue trying

---

Originally posted by [sergiootero](https://answers.ros.org/users/50338/sergiootero/) with karma: 26 on 2020-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Briant](https://answers.ros.org/users/68135/briant/) on 2021-01-18**:
Hi,Sergiootero,I just met the same problem,how did you solve this,appreciate it if you could reply when you see it